# LibreOffice macro user instruction

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a LibreOffice Calc document which needs to be downloaded by remote users. It uses macros - so they need to have macros enabled for it to work at all and there is no control over user machines.

To help with this I have a text message on the first tab telling them they need to enable macros and some instructions how. On document open I run a macro to remove this message - as long as they have macros enabled they never see it and all is well.

This solution works but is not perfect because:

- It will trigger the save changes dialogue even if they did no changes.
- It leaves the message removed if they save and pass the document directly to another user.
- Just doesn't feel like a well-engineered solution

Is there a better way to accomplish showing this message only when macros are not enabled?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.  Bec you will need some type of validation to check if macro is enabled.  
And the only way to do that is by using a macro.   However, how can that macro check if macro is enabled, if the macros are disabled?  My head hurts..

Comment: Maybe not, but any improvement in how to display the help message would be helpful. I'm thinking there might be a way with conditional formatting, will try that next.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but have you thought of hiding the sheet with the instructions on opening if macros are enabled and setting sthings up so closing the file would trigger unhiding the sheet with the instructions and saving before closing.

Comment: I don't want to do this in case the user made other changes which they don't want saved. Thanks though, any suggestions are still welcome.